# xml xpath jdbc row

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the below XML document returned on a SQL query. I'm able to return all values, but it returns all values for each row, rather than all values for a given row.

The expression `//jdbc:value[1]` returns all values. I'm not sure what I would do to limit the values to be returned for a given row. I'm assuming that I would grab all child `jdbc:values` under the parent attribute / reference of     `<jdbc:row jdbc:number="1">`.

Below is the document received.

```
<nds dtdversion="2.0" ndsversion="8.x" xmlns:jdbc="urn:dirxml:jdbc">
  <source>
    <product build="20160704_0401" instance="PeopleSoft JDBC driver" version="4.0.2.2">DirXML Driver for JDBC</product>
    <contact>NetIQ Corporation</contact>
  </source>
  <output>
    <jdbc:result-set event-id="0" jdbc:number-of-rows="2">
      <jdbc:row jdbc:number="1">
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="UID_IAM" jdbc:position="1" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>429332-0-2014-11-28</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="EFFDT" jdbc:position="2" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP">
          <jdbc:value>2014-11-28 00:00:00.0</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="PK_EMPLID" jdbc:position="3" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>429332</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="EMPL_STATUS" jdbc:position="4" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>T</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="EMPL_RCD" jdbc:position="5" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.NUMERIC">
          <jdbc:value>0</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="COALESCE(TERMINATION_DT,DATE'1916-01-01')" jdbc:position="6" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP">
          <jdbc:value>2014-11-27 00:00:00.0</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="NVL(JOB_DESCR,'NULL')" jdbc:position="7" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>Temporary Employee, hourly</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
      </jdbc:row>
      <jdbc:row jdbc:number="2">
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="UID_IAM" jdbc:position="1" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>429332-0-2015-07-22</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="EFFDT" jdbc:position="2" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP">
          <jdbc:value>2015-07-22 00:00:00.0</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="PK_EMPLID" jdbc:position="3" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>429332</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="EMPL_STATUS" jdbc:position="4" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>A</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="EMPL_RCD" jdbc:position="5" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.NUMERIC">
          <jdbc:value>0</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="COALESCE(TERMINATION_DT,DATE'1916-01-01')" jdbc:position="6" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP">
          <jdbc:value>1916-01-01 00:00:00.0</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
        <jdbc:column jdbc:name="NVL(JOB_DESCR,'NULL')" jdbc:position="7" jdbc:type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR">
          <jdbc:value>Affiliate</jdbc:value>
        </jdbc:column>
      </jdbc:row>
    </jdbc:result-set>
    <status event-id="0" level="success">
      <application>DirXML</application>
      <module>PeopleSoft JDBC driver</module>
      <object-dn></object-dn>
      <component>Subscriber</component>
    </status>
  </output>
</nds>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can select target row by its index or by `@jdbc:number` attribute value first, and then return corresponding `jdbc:value` elements. For example, returning all `jdbc:value` elements from the second row can be done using either of the following XPath :

```
//jdbc:row[2]/jdbc:column/jdbc:value
//jdbc:row[@jdbc:number=2]/jdbc:column/jdbc:value
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/43a1d5e2806d9da5027b44ed40e4ad0c)</kbd>**